# Order by a function result in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a table in my database containing geographical locations. I want to write a function that finds the location that is closest to a point. I tried this in NHibernate:

```
public Location GetClosestLocation(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    var closest = Session.QueryOver<Location>()
        .OrderBy(location => 
            (location.Latitude - latitude) + 
            (location.Longitude - longitude))
        .Asc.SingleOrDefault();

    return closest;
}
```

But it doesn't work - I get a runtime error.

What can I do to return the closest location? Is it possible to order by the result of a simple function with NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think QueryOver can understand expressions like that - it's use of lambda expressions is limited to identifying properties. There is an overload of OrderBy() that takes an IProjection, which provides for more flexibility.

With LINQ you should be able to use almost the same code as you tried:

```
var closest = Session.Query<Location>()
                     .OrderBy(location => 
                                 (location.Latitude - latitude) + 
                                 (location.Longitude - longitude))
                     .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like this. Just a note for anyone else who finds this question - remember to take Absolute of the distance!